# Nav list inline-block links don't work

Tags: css

I have trouble with my html/css code. I'm making a portfolio website and I have a horizontal navigation bar at the top, with `.png` images as navigation buttons and a `mouse-on/mouse-over` effect (the letters are supposed to turn grey with the mouse on it). 
I had quite some trouble aligning the buttons horizontally but now they're placed where they're supposed to be, the only thing is suddenly they don't work as links anymore and the `mouse-on/mouse-over` effect is gone.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<html>
<head>
<title>Menu</title>
<style type="text/css">

body 

{background-image:url('menubg.png');}

{background-color:#FFFFFF;}

#navlist{margin:0;position:relative;}
#navlist li{margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none;position:relative;top:0;}
#navlist li, #navlist a{height:64px;display:inline-block;}


#about{left:0px;width:145px;}
#about{background:url('about1.png')}
#about a:hover{background: url('about2.png')}

#amfi{left:0px;width:168px;}
#amfi{background:url('amfi1.png')}
#amfi a:hover{background: url('amfi2.png')}

#personal{left:0px;width:202px;}
#personal{background:url('personal1.png')}
#personal a:hover{background: url('personal2.png')}

#inspiration{left:0px;width:202px;}
#inspiration{background:url('inspiration1.png')}
#inspiration a:hover{background: url('inspiration2.png')}

#cv{left:0px;width:65px;}
#cv{background:url('cv1.png')}
#cv a:hover{background: url('cv2.png')}

#contact{left:0px;width:128px;}
#contact{background:url('contact1.png')}
#contact a:hover{background: url('contact2.png')}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<ul id="navlist">
  <li id="about"><a href="about.htm" target="main"></a></li>
  <li id="amfi"><a href="amfi.htm" target="main"></a></li>
  <li id="personal"><a href="personal.htm" target="main"></a></li>
  <li id="inspiration"><a href="inspiration.htm" target="main"></a></li>
  <li id="cv"><a href="cv.htm" target="main"></a></li>
  <li id="contact"><a href="contact.php" target="main"></a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my website is [here](http://www.esthervandergugten.com), where you can see my problem.

I would be really thankful if you can help me out!

Comment: You need to learn alot of CSS... This can be done with text

Comment: To add to @JahanzebKhan's point, you should look in to modern HTML practices as well, because your site is built using impractical coding, not to mention the plethora of better methods of solving your initial question, I can see from your website you are still using frames, which are deprecated in HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

I think problem here is you just place an anchor tag but in browser it is not added on particular action I mean you have given background image on `<a>` but there is no content present inside tag, keep in mind whenever you place hyperlink it should on some text or `img`

So instead of using empty tags use an image or text inside it and use javascript or jquery to change `img src` i.e

```
<a href="somthing.php" onmouseover="CHANGE_IMAGE();" onmouseout="REGAIN_IMAGE();"><img src="background/image.png"></a>
```

Comment: Tnx, I will check this as well but Tall BoY's answer works so I'm using that now!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
#about{left:0px;width:145px;}
#about{background:url('about1.png')}
#about:hover{background: url('about2.png')}
```

Or like this

```
#about a{left:0px;width:145px;}
#about a{background:url('about1.png')}
#about a:hover{background: url('about2.png')}
```

Answer (score 0):

your `<a>`s have no `width`and`height` the moment you will declare those in some way everything is going to be ok
i suggest to give property of `width`and`height` to `<a>` element instead of `<li>`
for example `#about a{width:145px;height:64px}` instead `#about{width:145px;height:64px}`

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your stylesheet and your issue will be solved.

```
#navlist li a {
    display: list-item;
}
```

Hope this helps.